# Connecting desktop computer to the internet through laptop wifi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop, desktop-computer, transfer

Due to some home network complications I have had to move my router to a seperate part of the house, therefore the wired network I had set up can no longer work. Before I find the time to go out and buy a Wifi adapter for my desktop PC, I have a laptop that uses a built in Wifi card to connect to my router and this can connect to the internet, and I was wondering if I could somehow access the internet on my desktop PC via my laptop.

I'm hoping for a not-so-complex solution as this will only be set up for a few days, but it is quite vital that my desktop computer gets internet access.

Does anyone have experience in this sort of thing and can help me out? Thanks.

Comment: What OS? This makes a lot of difference.

Comment: Sorry, this is Windows 7 on both my lappy and desktop :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Windows ICS.

Very easy to setup, although you may need a cross-over cable to connect from your laptop to desktop.

Go to Network Connection>Right Click on the Wireless connection>Properties>Sharing Tab> Set up to share to the local area connection.

Make sure your desktop is set for DHCP and not static ip address.

Comment: Thank you. :D Hasd a bit of trouble at first but it turned out to be COMODO firewall doing it's job a bit too well and blocking the connection :P Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Under OSX, you can go to System Preferences / Sharing and check Internet Sharing and you are done !

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 on my lappy and desktop, should have mentioned that earlier :P