# Using a laptop as a wifi adapter for desktop with linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, laptop, desktop-computer

I have a laptop running Linux Mint 13 with a working wifi card and a desktop with no wifi card running Arch Linux. I temporarily have no access to a Ethernet connection, so I'd like to use my laptop as a wifi adapter for my desktop.

I've done this previously with Windows 7 on both machines, and [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/123201/connecting-desktop-computer-to-the-internet-through-laptop-wifi) also has instructions for OS X, but is there a way to do this with Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set up a bridge between wifi and ethernet in your laptop: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man8/brctl.8.html

Then connect your laptop ethernet to the desktop's. An usual patch cable should work.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work, but I can't add my wireless adapter to the bridge unless it's in 4-address mode, and I can't connect to the internet in 4-address mode. Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems untenable given the poor interplay between my router (Apple timecapsule) and anything non-Apple (it won't support WDS). However, since this looks like the right solution in general I'm accepting it.

Comment: What means, you cannot add it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a standard access point for 20€, or want to buy one, set this to client mode and directly connect your ethernet.